# Is this french? what has been said?

Tags: apprentissage

I was in snapchat and someone was saying something in french (but not sure lol), could someone guess what she said?
I uploaded the audio [here](https://vocaroo.com/i/s1VAwfbMmvAf), it is just few seconds and it starts at 00:07 sec. First she said: "hey.. then something..

Comment: This isn't a transcription service. Some may however kindly answer these kinds of requests in [chat].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like "Mais bon c'était un but avec un penalty donc...".
It translates to "But well, it was a penalty goal so..."

Comment: Yes that is clearly what I heared too

Comment: Oh okay I guess you're right